# Bypassing a website's Security Certificate warning using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, certificate, runtime-error

I access a website through VBA. This website has a security certificate.

Is there a way to get through this warning and go straight to the webpage.

```
Sub Certificate()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE

    .Visible = True
    .navigate ("Website URL")

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    {Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))}--Optional

    'This is the security certificates webpage HTML
    'This clicks the not recommended but continue to website button
    IE.document.getElementsByName("overridelink").Item.Click

End With

End Sub
```

When I execute this code this line:

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("overridelink").Item.Click
```

gives me a

> Runtime error '91'

This code works when the security certificate warning pops up however it doesn't always pop up and goes straight to the website, giving me that error.

I've gone into internet options and unchecked everything that would cause that warning as well as adding it to trusted site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUTION! Use sparingly!**

If the **only** time you get an error with the line `IE.document.getElementsByName("overridelink").Item.Click` is because you don't need it, you can use this:

```
On Error Resume Next
IE.document.getElementsByName("overridelink").Item.Click
On Error Goto 0
```

instead of:

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("overridelink").Item.Click
```

---

**CAUTION! Read this:**

Make sure to include the `On Error Goto 0` line directly after the section you want the error ignored on, as that line resets the error-behavior to default. Otherwise, the `On Error Resume Next` will mask any and all other errors in the code following it. This can cause HUGE issues with code giving unexpected results for no apparent reason and/or attempts to troubleshoot problematic code.

Another issue: if the error-skipping enclosed code goes wrong for an unexpected reason, you won't have any way of catching this unless you set-up a more elaborate error catching section in your code.